# How to reduce vertical spacing between section headings and paragraphs?

Tags: sectioning, vertical-alignment

I have a problem in reducing vertical spacing between text and section/subsection headings. There is a lot of spacing between them. May be it is due to lot of graphics i am using. But anyhow, i could not fix it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: As a fast workaround you could use `\vspace*{-5mm}`

Comment: Could you give us a MWE to play with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use \raggedbottom, instead of the default \flushbottom in your preamble. Of course the inconvenience will be that all pages won't have the same text height.